# jquery convert to json

Tags: jquery, json

I have this data like so:

```
ID=300573&CarNo=1&Account=AAAA&AccountingDate=3%2F21%2F2013&Description=NewCar&CheckAmount=666666&ClearedAmount=-3446.5&ClearedDate=4%2F9%2F2013&Sent=S&SentDate=4%2F4%2F2013&Hold=&HoldDate=&Notes=BBB
```

which I got from:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('input').serialize()
```

How I convert this into json? It needs to be in json to for an ASP.NET API Controller

Comment: start with `serializeArray()` instead of `serialize()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var serialize = $(this).parent().parent().find('input').serialize();

var JsonData = JSON.stringify(serialize);
```

Comment: Some human readable words would help explain what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Jquery serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)** on Inputs which will returns array of objects

```
var Data = $(this).parent().parent().find('input').serializeArray()
```

Then use **[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** to convert it into Json string

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `serializeArray` to create an array of objects of the input values instead of `serialize`.

```
var ID = $(this).parent().parent().find('input').serializeArray();
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(ID);
```